# Separate Background and make the edges smooth with EmguCv

Tags: c#, emgucv, fo-dicom

im not familiar with EmguCv, i have a Dicomfile which i want to make the background black (0 value) and then make the edges smooth to have a nice shape.

I put the raw bytes in a bytes array, and applied Image.ThresholdBinary() as you see in code below. This is the image i wanna to modify its background and egdes. Thank you in advance.
[image]

```
var threshold = iimg.ThresholdBinaryInv(new Gray(20), new Gray(100));
```

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple method would be to apply a [blur](https://emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/871ef36a-a168-46c0-da58-21138615678e.htm) to the thresholded image, and then apply another threshold. That should give you a smoothed edge. It might also be possible to apply the blur to the original image instead depending on what effect you are after. While this will give you a smoother edge, there is no guarantee it will follow the desired contour any better.

You might be able to use level sets. My very rudimentary understanding of the method is that you should be able to configure it to balance feature following and smoothness. But I do not think this is implemented in OpenCV, and I would have no idea how to use it if it where.

Comment: Thank you @JonasH, i understand your algorithm but 2 times thresholding it may affect the quality.

Do you have any idea how can i make the background black?, i did it with my own implented algorithm, but now i want to do it with OpenCv, i tried the ThresholdToZero(new Gray(133)); (133 because the background has 132 as gray value). But it does not work!

Comment: @Anasse A thresholded image usually only has two color levels. Discussing "quality" at that stage seem weird. The result from the ThresholdBinaryInv  should be `dst(x, y) = src(x, y) > threshold ? 0 : max_value`. If you have pixels with zero values that are not displayed as black then it is an issue in the display-system.